# How can I tell the version of an ACCDB file?

Tags: ms-access

I have Access 2010. But every time I create and open a new database, the title bar says 2007. When the same accdb file is opened in someone else' Access 2010, it shows `(Access 2007-2010)`. Why is it so?

How can I tell if my database is a 2007 or 2010?

Comment: (Posting this as a comment because this question is closed) All `*.accdb` files share the same ACE format and are forward-and-backward compatible between Access versions 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019 so far): so they're identical. However, if you enable or use a new Access feature then the "minimum Access/ACE version required" field in the file's header will be set.

Comment: This field is at offset 0x14, and has the value `0x02` if the file can be opened in ACE 12 (Access 2007) or later. If you use an ACE 14 (Access 2010) feature (like Data Macros) then the value is `0x03` which prevents Access 2007 from opening the file. If you use an ACE 16 (Access 2016) feature (like `BigInt` support) then the field is set to `0x05`.  The values `0x00`, `0x01`, and `0x04` should never appear in-the-wild as `0x00` and `0x01` were used by older JET/MDB files, and `0x04` would have been used by ACE 14 (Access 2013) but Access 2013 didn't introduce any new incompatible features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that often versions of Access from one to next use the SAME file version. So for example Access 2002 and 2003 shared the SAME version. (there was NOT a 2002 version, and not a 2003 version, but a 2002/2003 version).

The same applies to Access 2007 and 2010. If you install the SP update to office 2010, then Access 2010 will thus show 2007-2010 as you note on the other computer. So this was a bit of a UI issue that was fixed when you install the sp update to office.

Keep in mind that just like Access 2002 and 2003 shared the same file version, the feature set in Access is different between the two versions. While in 2002/2003 this was not usually much of a problem, in Access 2010, there is a signification feature difference and thus using the 2007/2010 format with 2010 means you can VERY easy make changes to the accDB file that will result in the file NOT being able to be used with 2007.  If the database you are working on will need to be used by previous versions, you likely want to use the 2002/2003 format to prevent any 2010 features being inserted by accident and thus preventing the accDB file from being used by Access 2007.

So, until you install the SP update to office, Access 2010 only shows 2007 format when in fact it should show 2007-2010 format since they are the same format version of a file.

Answer (score 6):

You may find

```
CurrentProject.FileFormat
```

Suits

```
9 = Microsoft Access 2000
10 = Microsoft Access 2003
12 = Microsoft Access 2010
```

Comment: errr... but where do we find this `CurrentProject.FileFormat`?

Comment: You mean in Ctrl+G VB windows?

Comment: For those non Access people like myself.  
  Open the Access database.
  Ctrl+G for the VB windows (thanks Zhang)
  In the VB window you'll find an "Immediate" section at the bottom
  Type the following:
    "print CurrentProject.FileFormat"